# Add component level styles instead of global styles in angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am using an angular template [argon dashboard](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-dashboard) in my angular app and I moved all the template files to a separate module named **dashboard module**. Since I'm using different global styles in my project, to prevent style collisions, I imported the template styles in the **dashboard module components**.

**dashboard.componenet.scss**

```css
@import ' "src/assets/templates/argon-design-system/scss/argon.scss",'
```

And I added **dashboard.componenet.scss** file in the **styleUrls[]** array in all the template modules.

**navbar.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss', '../../dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

By doing this, I can see that most of the scss files being loaded and some not. So the dashboard doesn't render as expected. But when I add the URL **src/assets/templates/argon-design-system/scss/argon.scss** in the **angular.json** global styles everything works properly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: why don't you import the scss file into `styles.scss` file. You don't have to add `dashboard.scss` on every component.

Comment: @uiTeam324 as I mentioned "Im using different global styles in my project". If I import it in ```styles.scss``` it gonna collide with other styles in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I would say import it in navbar.component.scss instead since it keeps the style within the component.